# How to highlight points in point cloud on mouse over?

Tags: rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible in RViz to highlight a single point in a point cloud and then publish its coordinate?

**Edit:** By highlighting I mean get coordinates of the point on mouse moved.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215786/how-to-highlight-points-in-point-cloud-on-mouse-over?/) by [VitaliyProoks](https://answers.ros.org/users/882/vitaliyprooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can select a single point in the point cloud with the selection tool, and you can publish a point which you click on the screen, but I'm not sure you can do both. You might have to write an rviz plugin to accomplish this.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1